# Can I say 'I'm picking up' meaning 'My health is getting better'?

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

The verb 'pick up' has a meaning "improve" so, provided there's an appropriate context, I think 'I'm picking up' can mean "I'm convalescing". However, one of other senses of the word is the opposite, "to contract (an illness)". So can I or can't I use that phrase the way I described it?

Comment: Yes you can. The convalescing sense is an intransitive verb, but you pick up a bug or whatever. Not with the participle though: you are not "picking up a bug" as you would pick up a crumb from a plate.

Comment: I wouldn't say "I'm picking up" to mean my health is improving. If you say "The stock market is picking up.", that's unambiguous. But "I'm picking up." can mean "I'm cleaning the house."

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty seems OK to me. Question to someone who has been ill: "How are you now?" Answer "I'm picking up." Context is all, but I've never known it to mean "cleaning the house."